# C# AWS SQS Client inaccessible due to it's protection level

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

So I've been having an issue getting the example from AWS to work for C#. I copy the code below straight from their site and put it in my program, but when it calls client.ListQueues(request); it tells me that it's inaccessible due to it's protection level. I've spent time searching, but I can't figure out why this isn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var client = new AmazonSQSClient();

// List all queues that start with "aws".
var request = new ListQueuesRequest
{
  QueueNamePrefix = "aws"
};

var response = client.ListQueues(request);
var urls = response.QueueUrls;

if (urls.Any())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Queue URLs:");

  foreach (var url in urls)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("  " + url);
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("No queues.");
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the exact error message? Are you running this on an EC2 instance with a role, or on a computer with a credentials file? Have you given it a valid set of AWS credentials? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I'm getting this from Visual studio as an inline error, so it's not even when I run it, it wants me to change it to ListQueuesAsync. The error is "Error CS0122 'AmazonSQSClient.ListQueues(ListQueuesRequest)' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it can be found in docs for some platforms the method `ListQueues` is not available. The docs says:

> For .NET Core, PCL and Unity this operation is only available in asynchronous form. Please refer to ListQueuesAsync.

So you have to use the asynchronous method `ListQueuesAsync` and make your calling method asnyc. Your code should look like:

```
public async Task<Result> SomeAction()
{
    var client = new AmazonSQSClient();

    // List all queues that start with "aws".
    var request = new ListQueuesRequest
    {
        QueueNamePrefix = "aws"
    };

    var response = await client.ListQueuesAsync(request);

    // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm still confused why amazon would specify it exactly like I did on this site [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/sqs-apis-intro.html)  Did I miss something on that page or is their example just wrong?

Comment: @rammaidy Their example is correct for the classic .NET but when you use for example .NET Core it's not. In `ListQueues` method description there is a note about it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/MSQSListQueuesListQueuesRequest.html

Comment: I had the same problem with AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient.SendMail. Using SendMailAsync worked. Thanks much.